# TEAMS bot: Messages not received in messaging endpoint

Tags: bots, microsoft-teams, ngrok

On one hand, I have a web application running and tunneled with ngrok:

https://87db45c5.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:3978

If i paste the https URL in a browser, I can see in ngrok cmd window:

GET  /                         304 Not Modified
to check when a request is received

On the other hand, I have created an App for my TEAMS client, using the App Studio (Manifest Editor - Create...)

I only need a BOT to send messages to my web application within a team. Messaging extensions is not used.

After App creation I have:

- The bot (created from App Studio) available in dev.botframework.com/ (MyBots), with correct 'Messaging endpoint' and AppId (03a5d7c9-18cb-458e-9fd7-b3ec8ba6d67d). Microsoft Teams is added in Channel and is 'Running'.
- My App registered in portal.azure.com, with the same AppId & AppSecret
- My App/BOT available in the TEAMS team/chat (@bot)

I think I have all required parameters properly added, but when I send a message to my BOT in TEAMS ("@bot hello") I see no trace in the ngrok cmd window

In the past I had a bot running, but I had to restart the process from scratch.

Any idea about what I am missing?

Thanks in advance,

Diego

Comment: Ihave restarted ngrok tunnel and when I tried to change Messaging Endpoint in my bot (dev.botframework) to set the new URL I got this error: CorrelationID: |135be3a7a6bcdc45be9f675304d2a9ed.61951976_ Could it be related to my problem?

Comment: Can you force a hard refresh in your browser and try again? In Chrome, navigate the Settings tab, press F12 to open the dev console, then right click the refresh button and choose “empty cache and hard reload”. Then try make a change and save.

Comment: I did it and it works! Thanks!! But why reloading the browser makes Teams message to reach my ngrok??